# Conect smartchart with smarttable in Fiori

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

Hi i have 2 Hboxes in my view. First one is for smarttable and second one is for smart chart. Both of them are connected in one beforeRebind function where i add filter to Filters[] passed to backend.
Chart is simple summ type of value in one column from table (possible 4 values and summ of them is 100%).

What i want:
Chart and table are based on diferent OData. But when i add filter to table chart doesn't rebind and shows data for entire table (before adding filter).

Also i want to have one query to DB (now chart make one and table make one - before filtering the same entity-set but chart-one at the end adds up the occurrences of value)